# Spotipy/Spotify - How to put a spotipy script on a server?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am doing a **Spotipy** script that I want to automize and put it on a **server**.
By "automize" I mean that for the authentification I don't want to have to copy/paste the open URL (I'm using **Authorization Code Flow**), is it possible? Or maybe there is a way to catch that opened URL and paste it automatically to the program on the server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

You can use `Flask`: http://flask.pocoo.org/, which is a microframework for serving applications (your scripts).

This way, every time you go to URL on your browser (`Flask` default is `localhost:5000`), authorization code will run automatically, and you can then be redirected to your served pages, as long as you have templates (`html`) for them.

Here's an example of how you can implement one app:

https://github.com/datademofun/spotify-flask

And here's a Walkthrough of Authorization Code Flow using `Flask` and `Python`, with the Spotify API:

https://github.com/drshrey/spotify-flask-auth-example